# MySQL Select a SUM from table 1, and SUM form table 2 where they are joined

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a table "cats" that contains a budget column, project id column, and id column. Child to this is table "clocks", which contains a cat_id, and total_time.

I need to

```
SELECT the SUM of cats.budget WHERE project_id = 1
```

and also

```
SELECT SUM(clocks.total_time) WHERE cats.id = clocks.cat_id
```

I am having trouble returning the correct SUMs in a JOIN query, as it typically duplicates the SUM value for the cats table for every instance of clocks record that is found in the JOIN.

Example Query I have tried

```
SELECT a SUM(table1.column1), JOIN table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.cat_id, and SELECT SUM(table2.column2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why have you tagged mysql **and** sql-server?

Comment: @scsimon, my apologies, it must ahve been a miss-click in the recommended tags. I will try and remove that tag.

Comment: No worries. It was actually @MarkRotteveel who noticed it. The "suggested tags" can be misleading sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

seems you need a inner join

```
select sum(cats.budget)/count(clocks.*), SUM(clocks.total_time)
from cats 
inner join clocks on cats.id = clocks.cat_id
where cats.project_id =1;
```

Comment: This was my initial attempt, but this returns a SUM of SUM(cats.budget) for every clocks record found: meaning if 4 clocks records are found, the SUM(cats.budget) gets added to itself 4 times

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` to an *already aggregated* `clocks` table:

```
select t1.id, sum(t1.budget) as total_budget, t2.total_time
from cats as t1
inner join (
   select cat_id, SUM(total_time) as total_time
   from clocks 
   group by cat_id) as t2 on t1.id = t2.cat_id
where t1.project_id =1
group by t1.id
```

The derived table used in the query above returns the `SUM` of `total_time` per `cat_id`. The query works in MySQL. For SQL Server you need to add `t2.total_time` field in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Thank you! this has gotten me very close, but I still see SUM differences in the clocks.total_time. I have swapped the "group by cat_id) as t2 on t1.id = t2.cat_id" to instead use "group by proj_id) on t1.proj_id = t2.proj_id" as the clocks table also carries its parent project id as well

Comment: @nocc_ninja I think you have to keep grouping as it is and also filter by `project_id =1` in the subquery as well.